# Reference of pointer to structure inside of structure inside of another structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct, reference, dynamic-memory-allocation

Before anything these are the links for the complete code:

**Note**: Code was fixed. See older versions to look up the incorrect code.

- [Source](https://github.com/LeoVen/EEP/blob/master/DataStructures/DataStructures/C/Structures/Vector.c)
- [Header](https://github.com/LeoVen/EEP/blob/master/DataStructures/DataStructures/C/Headers/Vector.h)
- [Tests](https://github.com/LeoVen/EEP/blob/master/DataStructures/DataStructures/C/Tests/VectorTests.c)

I've been trying to initialize a Vector (like in linear algebra) by referencing it in the arguments like this:

```
int buildNormalVector(double x, double y, double z, Vector **v)
{
    (*v) = (Vector *)malloc(sizeof(Vector *));
    (*v)->x = x;
    (*v)->y = y;
    (*v)->z = z;
    (*v)->base = (Basis *)malloc(sizeof(Basis *));
    buildSimpleVector(1, 0, 0, &((*v)->base->i));
    buildSimpleVector(0, 1, 0, &((*v)->base->j));
    buildSimpleVector(0, 0, 1, &((*v)->base->k));
    return v;
}
```

Where the structure of a `Vector` goes like this:

```
typedef struct Vector Vector;
typedef struct SimpleVector SimpleVector;
typedef struct Basis Basis;

struct Vector {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    Basis *base;
};

struct Basis {
    SimpleVector *i;
    SimpleVector *j;
    SimpleVector *k;
};

struct SimpleVector {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};
```

Note this line:

```
buildSimpleVector(1, 0, 0, &((*v)->base->i));
```

And here is how I initialize each `SimpleVector` that will work as a basis:

```
int buildSimpleVector(double x, double y, double z, SimpleVector **v)
{
    (*v) = (SimpleVector *)malloc(sizeof(SimpleVector *));
    (*v)->x = x;
    (*v)->y = y;
    (*v)->z = z;
    return 0;
}
```

I've been struggling to find the correct way to pass a reference to the `i, j, k` vector basis of that vector. I've tried `&(*((*v)->base)->k)`aswell but to me it is too confusing and it doesn't work. The example above works but only half of the time and gives a read access violation error at this line:

```
(*v) = (SimpleVector *)malloc(sizeof(SimpleVector *));
```

Sometimes the program goes through all tests, sometimes it doesn't (which is the strangest part of this issue).

I know for sure that to change the `Vector *v` that was declared at main has to be passed by reference like `Vector **v` and then I can do `(*v) = malloc and change it..` to change the original one, and that the parentheses is needed due to operators precedence. So is the problem when I pass the reference of the `SimpleVector` to build it or when I allocate the `Vector`? Can I do something like this?

```
Vector *v;
buildNormalVector( 1, 2, 3, &v);
```

There are probably too many questions about structures, pointers and memory allocation, so if you know any good book to read or internet page that can explain all these concepts I would greatly appreciate it!

**Edit**:

I've been using Visual Studio 2017 to compile and run the program

Comment: Your allocating the size of a pointer all over, for example with `sizeof(SimpleVector *)`. I don't see where you actually allocate room for the `sizeof(SimpleVector)` itself? Perhaps your missing a second `malloc` following all your `malloc`s?

Comment: Yes, dumb me doesn't know that ```sizeof(SimpleVector *)``` is quite different from ```sizeof(SimpleVector)```. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a consistent problem with memory allocation:

```
(*v) = (Vector *)malloc(sizeof(Vector *));

(*v)->base = (Basis *)malloc(sizeof(Basis *));

(*v) = (SimpleVector *)malloc(sizeof(SimpleVector *));
```

The allocated memory is too small to hold your structures. Change it to:

```
(*v) = malloc(sizeof(Vector));

(*v)->base = malloc(sizeof(Basis));

(*v) = malloc(sizeof(SimpleVector));
```

Also, in your test you never release the allocated memory.

You should not return pointer as integer in:

```
int buildNormalVector(double x, double y, double z, Vector **v)
(*v) = (Vector *)malloc(sizeof(Vector *));
//
 return v;
}
```

Wrong format `"%d"` for `double x, y, z` in

```
void displayVector(Vector *v)
{
    printf("\nVector\n[%8.2lf i ]\n[%8.2lf j ]\n[%8.2lf k ]", v->x, v->y, v->z);
    printf("\nBase\n[%d, %d, %d], [%d, %d, %d], [%d, %d, %d]\n",
        v->base->i->x, v->base->i->y, v->base->i->z,
        v->base->j->x, v->base->j->y, v->base->j->z,
        v->base->k->x, v->base->k->y, v->base->k->z);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I should've known that ```sizeof(Vector *)``` is different from ```sizeof(Vector)```. Also freeing all those vectors was removed because at some point I was hitting a ```free``` on an uninitialized pointer and that is probably why I was running this code and sometimes working, sometimes not. Also thanks for noticing other mistakes as I went rushing this code to present it tomorrow.

Comment: @LeoVen You are welcome! Mistakes happens, I like your code overall. Keep up good work. Compile with code with compiler options `/Wall` , `/w4` to catch many issues. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe.aspx)